# Snap cubes to each other

Tags: snapping

I am trying to snap the center of the face of the cube to the center of edge of the rectangular prism as shown in the picture but I cannot do it. Can you describe me how? Yes I know the magnet icon for snapping, and yes I know all those options near magnet icon there but which one ? Please describe in detail what mode, which is selected, how and where to grab, which key, which mouse click and its sequence etc. It has been 2 days and I just cannot do it, this is very frustrating. I tried every combination I believe. Watched several tutorials...  It just behaves as it pleases and snaps to funny locations when I try to grab with G and move it. Either snapping in blender needs significant improvements or I cannot do it - and I used several drawing programs before and never had issue with snapping.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to remember, that the origin point wants to snap to the target, so you first have to set the origin point of the moving object to the face.

1. select the face
2. shift-s -> selection to cursor
3. object mode -> set origin to cursor
4. snapping edge center
5. move it

[image]

Comment: ahh ok thanks a lot... finally... and just toi make sure. i first go to edit mode, select the face there, and then i move back to object mode right? so this cannot be done fully in object mode then, without setting the center to cursor like this? I mean i was able to do some other snapping in object mode without setting the origin of cube to cursor, but not this one. and if i do not set the cursor there, it seemed like it grabs wherever my mouse was, is it the case? so regardless, in any type of snapping, the proper way is to set origin to cursor like you did?

Comment: i think so, yes. Or you use lemon's answer, if you are using a newer Blender version.

Answer (score 5):

In version 4.0, you can use <kbd>B</kbd>, while grabbing the mesh, to select the base point which will then be the point to place.

After that drag over the other mesh and validate the translation when the symbol indicating the edge center appaears:

[image]

The circle indicates face center, triangle edge center, square vertices.

[4.0 release notes](https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.0/modeling/), for more information.

Comment: Are you in edit mode while doing this? Which options near magnet icon did you select? I had tried with B also 1000 times and could not do it. Do you press B twice? do you press G first and then grab and then B? They made all these as if we must perform actions like in mission impossible... Can you write in more detail if possible? I really appreciate

Comment: I cannot do as you do. Can you give more details step by step? which mode, what is selected for magnet options and then vertices, and then on the left side of screen between move select transform and then at what point we press all these. I lost 2 days trying to figure this out. just because some guys thought everyone was born with knowledge about what to click when. this is very counterintuitive and difficult.

Comment: This is new things in v4.0. You grab G, as usual. Then use B (still grabbing) and click on the element you want to place (here the face, indicated by a circle symbol). Then continue grabbing until you see the triangle symbol that indicates the edge center and at this step validate the grab.